# Prevent netbeans php Debug from opening a new tab in browser

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp, xdebug

I have an annoying issue, 
every time I try to debug in netbeans a single php file (which is located in my PHP project) it automatically opens my chrome browser with the following url:

```
"path_to_php_file.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug"
```

and when I stop the debug session it opens a new tab again:

```
"path_to_php_file.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=netbeans-xdebug"
```

this is so annoying, anyone knows how to prevent that automatic browser opening?

Edit: what I really try to achieve here is to stop the browser automatically jump to my foreground with every single DEBUG_START and DEBUG_END...

Comment: How would the xdebug socket know when it has started and stopped then?

Comment: Stop that and you stop XDEBUG working. Its that that is making the connection between NetBeans and XDEBUG

Comment: is it possible starting it without the browser jumping to my foreground?

Comment: The browser is being activated, so it comes to the fore, thats just the way it is

Comment: Add a second monitor. IDE on one, browser on the other. Then you won't be so bugged ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hah, I have found a work around for this automatic browser open by simple doing the following:

```
right click project --> properties --> browser --> Embdedded WebKit Browser
```

that way it will open in the ide which is much better because I can tweak it from there instead bringing my browser to the foreground every time :)

Answer (score 0):

Project Properties - Run Configurations - Run as: Local Web Site, then Advanced - Do Not Open Web Browser

At this point you might need to also setup the mapping if you're running your PHP service in a docker container.